# Django не видит статические файлы при выключенном debug'е

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Когда выключил debug (debug = False), все css исчезли с сайта.

Comment: collectstatic нужно делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОТВЕТ:
{% load staticfiles %}
Должна быть после DOCTYPE

Answer (score 8):

Документация по теме:

- [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/).
- [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/).

`DEBUG=True` предназначен только для разработки и не подходит для прода.

При `DEBUG=False` вам нужно статичные файла раздавать вашим веб-сервером (Apache/nginx), а не с помощью Django.

Answer (score 2):

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Скопирует содержимое папок static из ваших приложений в папку STATIC_ROOT, определяется в settings.py. По умолчанию STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Если вам надо автоматически собирать статику при включенном дебаге, то есть батарейка
[django-static-autocollect](https://pypi.org/project/django-static-autocollect/)

Comment: Работает через раз

Comment: Ага, есть такое, если очень быстро сохранять файл, то будет срабатывать через раз. Я для этих целей вообще делал полный изврат, не советую, но всё же расскажу. У меня был .sh скрипт, который каждые 2 секунды собирал статику, когда я его запускал. Это ещё хуже, хоть и autocollect кстати грузит целиком 1 ядро, что тоже не есть гуд. Вообще по хорошему у вас для прода и для разработки должно быть два разных сервера, поэтому либо терпеть задержки autocollect и cpuload 100% на ядро, либо писать самоделки, которые будут нехило тоже грузить систему, если у вас 500 статик-файлов

Comment: Я добавил в cron команду на collectstatic --noinput, каждые 5 минут собирает статик

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, зачем? Если при разработке после каждой правки требуется проверить работоспособность?